# Error while Running ztemyapp MTS Mblaze modem in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management

My Ubuntu version is

```
E7440:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

> ~$uname -a
>       Linux ss-Latitude-E7440 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I have installed *MTS Mblaze* application.

But I get the following error while running application.

> ~# ztemtapp
>   /usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/bin/App: error while loading shared libraries: libQtGui.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried to install Qt.

```
apt-get install libQtGui.so.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libQtGui.so.4
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libQtGui.so.4'
```

Answer (score 1):

Reason: In 64 bit system , 32 application missing shared libraries.

Solution:

Found the missing libraries using`ldd`

added foreign architecture:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Installed i386 version of missing libraries one by one.

Now it is working.